# Understanding a Boolean conjunction statement in Rails method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, boolean-expression

This might be a trivial point, but I don't understand it and it bothers me.
Going through the [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://railstutorial.org) by Michael Hartl, there is this method definition :

```
 def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      redirect_to user
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = "Invalid email/password combination"
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

What I don't understand is why the conjunction

```
user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
```

is neccessary. Surely, there is no case in which user.authenticate will return "true" if the user object is empty, and hence, nil.  Is this just a matter of style, or does 'user &&' do something subtle in this expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to do this part: `user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])` without first knowing if the object exists will throw an error. So you need to make sure you have the `user` object before you try to run `.authenticate` on it. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yep. Doing this in a console throws up a "no method error"  I thought that ruby would use the exit value of the function (which should be "nil" on an error, right?) for the Boolean comparison, but maybe halting on error is a safer behavior.

Answer (score 2):

`if user` would be the same as `if user.present?`. So if its nil, it goes to the else statement, if its true, then it runs the second statement being `user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])`

Comment: My thought was that if there was no user, then user.authenticate(whatever) would simply return false, thus no need for the user.present? test.  However, as @aspencer8111 pointed out, trying to invoke an undefined method on an object will not return "false" but will halt execution.  But thank you for your answer, sorry I can only accept one.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just ask Ruby herself about the difference?

```
user = nil

if user && user.authenticate(nil) then end

if user user.authenticate(nil) then end
# NoMethodError: undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass
```

As you can see, [`nil`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/NilClass.html) doesn't have an `authenticate` method (why would it), so trying to call `authenticate` on `nil` will [`raise`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-raise) a [`NoMethodError`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/NoMethodError.html).

Boolean operators are evaluated lazily from left to right (sometimes known as "short-circuiting") only as far as is needed to determine the result. Since `user` is `nil`, it is already known that the result of the entire conditional *must* be falsy, no matter what the right operand is, and so the right operand is never evaluated, and therefore, the non-existing method is never called.

---

Note: I'm not trying to be glib here, I'm trying to show you a powerful learning tool: if you are wondering "what happens if I do XYZ", just do XYZ and see what happens! Contrary, to, say, chemistry, experimenting is completely safe in programming. (Well … you could delete your harddrive, if you're really stupid, but if you do your experiments in a sandboxed environment, you'll be fine. Accidentally deleting valuable data is highly unlikely unless you are toying around with the `File` or `FileUtils` classes.)